# Is there a framework for simple, asynchronous, HTTP integration I/O?

Tags: java, web-services, scala, asynchronous, netty

The web service I need to build:

1. receives an HTTP request;
2. makes requests to multiple other web services in parallel;
3. upon receiving all results from the other services, aggregates them and sends a response.

The majority of "time" spent by this server will be in waiting for the other services to respond. Hence, I'd really like to avoid holding onto blocking threads for both the request-serving code and the parallel web service requests. So we're talking async on the incoming side and async on the outgoing side so that, ideally, if there are many requests "in flight" but they are all waiting on the web services to respond, all the server's threads should be in a pool just waiting for work.

Is there a framework that is able to do this almost out of the box, preferably by bolting together a few very simple constructs?

I'm well-versed with Java and Scala, so something in that ecosystem would be ideal, but I would happily switch to another language if there is a solution that is demonstrably simpler. I have some knowledge of actors/Akka and Reactor, so I'd be happy to employ either of those if someone can show how they would fit together *simply* to provide the async on both sides.

Comment: Have you looked at netty? http://netty.io/

Comment: @Raji *|almost out of the box, preferably by bolting together a few **very simple** constructs|* oh yeah, definitely netty.

Comment: Play or Spray (spray.io)

Comment: Spring boot webflux

Answer (score 1):

`Play Framework` makes it easy to build web applications with Java & Scala.

**Play is based on a lightweight, stateless, web-friendly architecture.
Built on Akka, Play provides predictable and minimal resource consumption (CPU, memory, threads) for highly-scalable applications.**

you can use play framework

[image]

**Why Play Framework ?**

1. Developer friendly
2. Scale predictably
3. Modern web & mobile
4. Solid & fast
5. Massive ecosystem

you can read case study of enterprises that are using `play framework` and `scala`

[case studies](http://www.typesafe.com/company/casestudies)

[play framework](http://www.typesafe.com/platform/runtime/playframework)

Comment: Although play is great, perhaps you can skip marketing speeches? E.g. it is surprising to see *predictable and minimal resource consumption* in a context of JVM

Answer (score 0):

We use [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) for a similar project and it fits perfectly to the requirements. It provides both Java and XML DSL and I think its simple enough